# What is solution of this expression

Tags: logarithms

I am new to logarithms, and I need to find out the solution set of this expression.

$$x^{\log_a x} = (a^\pi)^{(\log_a x)^3} \\ a \in \mathbb{N} , a>0 ,a \neq 1$$

Comment: Is there a $3$ in the expression on the right?

Comment: @Anurag A Yes in RHS, it is, a raised to the power π , which is again raised to the power: cube of log of x to the base a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\log_a x=t$, then $a^t=x$. Use this in the equation given to write
\begin{align*}
x^{\log_a x} & = (a^\pi)^{(\log_a x)^3}\\
x^{t}&=a^{\pi t^3}\\
a^{t^2} & = a^{\pi t^3}\\
t^2&=\pi t^3. 
\end{align*}
Thus either $t=\log_a x=0$ or $t=\log_a x=\frac{1}{\pi}$. This means $x=1$ or $x=a^{\frac{1}{\pi}}$